# Rich text Editor for rtf format, in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, richtextbox, rtf, richtext

I know there are al sorts of javascript Rich text editors out there.

But I have yet to come across one that is rtf format (NOT HTML).

And free.

I just spent the last few hours implementing Ckeditor, only to find that it doesnt recognise the rtf formatted notes in the database. :(

So what I need is RTF editor for ASP.NET MVC3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that exists. Not even TinyMCE and XStandard support RTF.

You'll have to use an RTF-to-HTML Converter (like [this one](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/richedit/conversions/article.php/c5377)) and store your rich text in HTML instead.

Comment: The problem is the desktop application (which has been running for years), uses rtf format. I could try and convert on the fly, to and from the database.

Comment: TinyMCE might support Copy/Paste from your desktop application, if that is any help... Same as it supports Copy/Paste from Word.

Comment: Aye, I dont doubt that I can get it form rtf to html, What I meant was I would have to convert the desktop app code to support the different format. Something id prefer not to do, since I am not the author of it all. (created years ago by someone else in the company)